# IMPORTXML returns blank results

Tags: xml, google-sheets, xml-parsing, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import data from `https://www67.myfantasyleague.com/2019/export?TYPE=liveScoring&L=64741&APIKEY=&W=1&DETAILS=1` into a Google Sheet to parse. Specially I want to return each franchise id and which players are subchildren.

I tried two formulas in the google sheet and can't figure out why I'm not getting any results back. No errors, just a blank cell.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www67.myfantasyleague.com/2019/export?TYPE=liveScoring&L=64741&APIKEY=&W=1&DETAILS=1&JSON=0","/"

=IMPORTXML("https://www67.myfantasyleague.com/2019/export?TYPE=liveScoring&L=64741&APIKEY=&W=1&DETAILS=1","//franchise[@id='0006']//players")
```

[Link to Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xT0zmbizbGUJX5kFP30rPXCyBMpYJCw2IaGR9mioBEc/edit?usp=sharing)

What am I doing wrong here? I can get results if I use IMPORTDATA, but I need the structure the XML provides to make queries correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is a snippit of the XML where I want all the player ids under each franchise id (player ids can be under multiple franchise ids, fyi)

```
<liveScoring week="1">
<matchup>
<franchise id="0006" score="109.52" gameSecondsRemaining="0" playersYetToPlay="0" playersCurrentlyPlaying="0" isHome="0">
<players>
<player id="7393" score="25.30" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="starter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="14056" score="21.62" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="starter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="11672" score="0.00" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="nonstarter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="11644" score="14.56" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="starter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="12634" score="7.50" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="starter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="11671" score="4.80" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="starter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="10261" score="0.00" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="nonstarter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="9662" score="16.38" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="starter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="13722" score="14.40" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="nonstarter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="13590" score="9.40" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="nonstarter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="13633" score="10.40" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="nonstarter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="9988" score="0.00" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="nonstarter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="13678" score="0.00" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="nonstarter" updatedStats=""/>
</players>
</franchise>
<franchise id="0005" score="163.78" gameSecondsRemaining="0" playersYetToPlay="0" playersCurrentlyPlaying="0" isHome="1">
<players>
<player id="12184" score="24.30" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="nonstarter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="11644" score="14.56" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="starter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="11227" score="12.70" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="nonstarter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="10261" score="0.00" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="nonstarter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="13636" score="5.50" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="nonstarter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="9427" score="0.00" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="nonstarter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="12154" score="0.00" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="nonstarter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="10273" score="5.36" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="starter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="13606" score="10.30" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="nonstarter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="13138" score="0.00" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="nonstarter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="13968" score="0.00" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="nonstarter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="9431" score="27.60" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="nonstarter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="12197" score="3.00" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="nonstarter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="12157" score="13.00" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="starter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="13130" score="42.90" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="starter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="12263" score="17.50" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="nonstarter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="11192" score="23.20" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="starter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="11660" score="4.10" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="nonstarter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="11677" score="3.70" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="nonstarter" updatedStats=""/>
<player id="11257" score="7.00" gameSecondsRemaining="0" status="starter" updatedStats=""/>
</players>
</franchise>
</matchup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve "player ID" using "franchise ID".
- You want to achieve this using IMPORTXML.
- You want to know that the values from `"/"` and `"//franchise[@id='0006']//players"` are the empty.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Modification points:

- When I saw the XML data, the text is not set. By this, the xpaths of `"/"` and `"//franchise[@id='0006']//players"` return the empty.

  - In your case, it is required to retrieve the values of IDs using the attribute.

### Modified formulas:

For the following formulas, the URL of `https://www67.myfantasyleague.com/2019/export?TYPE=liveScoring&L=64741&APIKEY=&W=1&DETAILS=1` is put in the cell `A1`.

#### Patten 1:

When you want to retrieve all IDs, how about ths following formula?

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//@id")
```

#### Patten 2:

When you want to retrieve the player's IDs of the franchise ID of "0006", how about ths following formula?

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//franchise[@id='0006']//player/@id")
```

Result:

[image]

### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: this is perfect!!!! Thank you so much! I didn't realize the xpath was my issue. Can you tell me how I can get the status results for each player under the 0006 franchise? You are amazing! Cheers!

Comment: @Bricky Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, when you want to retrieve the values of "status" using the franchise ID, how about this? `=IMPORTXML(A1,"//franchise[@id='0006']//player/@status")` If I misunderstood your additional question, I apologize.

Comment: you are amazing and a boon to this community! Thank you! You saved me hours of precious time